# Regex with repetative combination

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex with following condition:

1. Start and End with 123456(5-7 digit Number) or CR-0000001234(CR-any 10 digit No)
2. Only two number can be separated with , and space.
   3) this check will be repetative in nature ..

I have already written it , but it matches only first two not repetitive manner :

```
([cC][rR][0-9]{10}|[0-9]{5,7})[,][ ][0-9]{5,7}$|([cC][R][0-9]{10}|[0-9]{5,7})?[,][ ][cC][rR][0-9]{10}$|([cC][rR][0-9]{10})|([0-9]{5,7})
```

It matches only two combinations :

```
123456, CR1234567890 
123456, 123456
```

But

123456, 123456, 123456 is not working .

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Can you use `i` modifier to make the pattern case-insensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex like below.

```
^(?:[cC][rR][0-9]{10}|[0-9]{5,7})(?:, (?:[cC][rR][0-9]{10}|[0-9]{5,7}))+$
```

If you also want to match exactly onw word then change `+` in the above to `*`.

```
^(?:[cC][rR][0-9]{10}|[0-9]{5,7})(?:, (?:[cC][rR][0-9]{10}|[0-9]{5,7}))*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nW4gP5/1)